# Some Special Letters

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> First, add me to I,
>
> You may get me back -
>
> But I won't be exactly the same.
>
> I might be sweet,
>
> I might be Jewish,
>
> I might be a city plural.
>
> Or else:
>
> Add me to salt,
>
> You may need to turn around.
>
> Add me (maybe my imposter) to time,
>
> You may lighten up a little.
>
> Add me to a set,
>
> You'll find yourself in various places.

What is this 'word'/special letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> Somer

First, add me to I,

You may get me back -

But I won't be exactly the same.

> Isomer, a compound with the same chemical formula but a different structure

I might be sweet,

> Somersweet, a sugar replacement
>  **OP's suggestion:** S'more: A s'more (sometimes spelled smore) is a traditional nighttime campfire treat popular in the United States and Canada, consisting of a fire-roasted marshmallow and a layer of chocolate sandwiched between two pieces of graham cracker.

I might be Jewish,

> Somers, a jewish name
>  **OP's suggestion** - Omer(s): (unit), an ancient unit of measure used in the era of the ancient Temple in Jerusalem AND Counting of the Omer, Jewish ritual during the forty-nine days between Passover and the Feast of Weeks

I might be a city plural.

> anagram for the plural of Orem, Utah
>  **OP's suggestion:** Rome(s), Italy

You may need to turn around.

> Somersalt

Add me (maybe my imposter) to time,

You may lighten up a little.

> Summer time

Add me to a set,

You'll find yourself in various places.

> Somerset, a county in England
>  **OP's suggestion**: Also places in Australia, Canada, Bermuda, the U.S.

Comment: Yep, this is it. Can you figure out the rest of the first paragraph?

Comment: Was exactly my thought. The last one is probably you failing a somerset and  getting dizzy.

Comment: Somersweet appears to be some kind of sugar replacement, never heard of it before now! Somers is a jewish name, and i still can't figure out the city!

Comment: @Luke4792 Think about 'isomers' of 'somer'

Comment: Is it an anagram for the plural of Orem, Utah?

Comment: There is a much more famous city, but you can put your suggests if you like and I will add a separate note.

Comment: It's an anagram of Rome: much more common than Orem, Utah.

Comment: Wow, I was overthinking it too much.

Comment: I overlooked it as well, hence why that line was only added in a later edit.